# MOSS 2007 - user search on add new user to the site collection - "No exact match was found."

Tags: sharepoint-2007

please some help.
In our company we have MOSS 2007 and on separate server active directory with all the users.
Let say that we have company domain named domain.abc and sharepoint server on sharepoint (full path is sharepoint.domain.abc, but it is everywhere written just sharepoint for location). The server with AD is on users.domain.abc.
It's a simple setup. We successfully connected the users.domain.abc with our sharepoint server- and in SSP1 the profile import is working (we can get all the people and new ones are regularly added), importing is working with no errors or warnings in logs.
The problem is that when we want to add users in the sharepoint site- there is an error saying: No exact match was found. But existing users on the site can be found in this search box- just cannot add new ones.

Ofcourse we google it- and checked also on this forum for the solutions, and the only thing that we found was with various solutions with Stsadm operations:

- Setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath - we tried with:

  stsadm -o setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -path "DC=sharepoint,DC=domain.abc,DC=local" –url http:// sharepoint and it did not worked
- Then with peoplepicker:

  stsadm -o setproperty -url http:// sharepoint -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:domain.abc,domain:sharepoint.domain.abc,domain\username,password"

  or

  stsadm -o setproperty -url http:// sharepoint -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:domain.abc,domain:sharepoint,domain\username,password"

  or

  stsadm -o setproperty -url http:// sharepoint -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:sharepoint,domain\username,password"

  or

  stsadm -o setproperty -url http:// sharepoint -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:sharepoint.domain.abc,domain\username,password"

  they all did not worked

Kindly appreciate for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

What was the issue?

1. I enabled (during all the tries to solve the problem) setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath- it's a no-no
2. Then our forrest has only one domain (so the forrest and domain have same address).
3. The users don't add to the site by itself if you don't push the site.

Solution:

1. stsadm -o setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath -path "" -url http://sharepoint
2. stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:domain.abc,domain\username,password;domain:domain.abc,domain\username,password" -url http://sharepoint
3. It helps (!) if the user tries to connect to the site before he is added or anything. Once that happens - you can search for the user in the people-picker.
4. Important: iisreset /noforce

Well it helped for me- hope it will help you. Cheers

Comment: What do you mean "it helps if the user tries to connect first"?  Is that step required?   Because thats the issue I am having right now... can't add someone until they attempt to connect once first

Answer (score -1):

Had same issue and fixed it with correct passwords in search account and in script.